# Inserting data from the xml doc to the xsl

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I am a beginner at using XSL and XML. I have a problem with fetching the data from the XML document and using it in the XSL. Currently I am trying different methods but can't seem to get it right and I will need to use this technique throughout to complete the project. Once I can do it to one I will be able to do throughout the page.

Here is samples from my XML and my XSL document:

```
<storelocator> 
    <!--Parent element containing all text on the page-->
    <content_text> 
        <title>
            <titlename>Store Locator</titlename> 
        </title>
        <title>
            <subtitle>FIND A STORE</subtitle>
        </title>
        <title>
            <countrydropdown>Country</countrydropdown>
        </title>
        <title>
            <address>Steet Address, City, Sate/Province OR Postal/Zip Code</address>
        </title>
        <title>
            <radiusdropdown>Radius</radiusdropdown>
        </title>
        <title>
            <featuredstore>FEATURED STORE</featuredstore>
        </title>
        <title>
            <storelocation>Newbury Street, Boston, MA USA</storelocation>
        </title>
</storelocator>
```

Here is the XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
<body bgcolor="white">

<div id="container" style="100%">

<div id="header" style="background: url('header.png'); height:30px;"></div>

<div id="content_container" align="center" style="text-transform: uppercase; font-family: tahoma; font-weight: normal; font-size: 0.8em">
    <div id="content" align="left" style="background-color:blue;height:845px;width:848px">

   <xsl:value-of select="titlename"/> <!--here I was trying to import the text from XML DOC-->

<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
    <img src="image.png" align="left"/><br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>

</div>
</div>

<div id="footer" style="background-color:black;clear:both;text-align:center;height:20px"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>

</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Basically what I am trying to do is import the "store locator" title so that it displays above the image but currently nothing appears when it is opened in browser. I would much appreciate some help as I have been trying to do it for a while.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the most important things to remember in XSLT is that all paths are going to be based on context. In your example, the context is `/` because in your template, you're matching `/`. You can't go straight from `/` to `titlename`.

Try changing your `xsl:value-of` to:

```
<xsl:value-of select="storelocator/content_text/title/titlename"/>
```

Also, the XSLT isn't "importing" your XML; it's transforming it. If you're just opening the XSLT in the browser, this isn't going to work. To get the transform to work in a browser when opening the XML, you'll have to add a processing instruction that points to your XSLT:

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="test.xsl"?>
<storelocator> 
...
</storelocator>
```